# Vue js : how to show length of array JSON

Tags: vue.js

in my Vue js project, i wanted to show the length of specific data in API and when i wrote code below i got the status `sold` length = 5 repeated 5 times, while i want to show only one time like 5 only
is there a way to do it?

```html
<span class="text-success mr-2" v-for="(flatno,index) in Flats " 
:key="index" v-show="flatno.status ==='sold'" >   
   {{flatno.status.length}}
</span>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend to define a computed property called `flatSoldStatusLength` that returns the length of the flats with status equals to `sold` :

```js
computed:{
  flatSoldStatusLength(){
    return this.Flats.filter(flat=>flat.status==='sold').length;
  }
}
```

in template :

```html
<span class="text-success mr-2"  >   
   {{flatSoldStatusLength}}
</span>
```

Comment: Or just `{{Flats.length}}` to show the length of all results.  I think you've made a good guess that the OP wants to know how many meet the `sold` condition.